# How to use SUM with INNER JOIN from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sum

I am stuck on a query where i have to show list of manufacturers and the Amount of Loan they took and Amount of Refund they returned. i have generated the query but i want to sum total no: of refunds of a manufacturer and total no: of Loans manufacturer has taken. and the difference , that is LoanTaken - RefundAmount = Remaining Amount. If its possible in the query.

```
SELECT MM.*, ML.*, MR.*  FROM microfinance_manufacturers AS MM 
                INNER JOIN manufacturer_loans AS ML ON MM.ManufacturerId = Ml.ManufacturerId 
                INNER JOIN manufacturer_refunds AS MR ON MM.ManufacturerId = MR.manufacturerId
                WHERE 1 = 1

ManufacturerId  FirstName  LastName  Gender  Religion  PhoneNumber  EmailAddress  Notes              CustomerAddedDateTime  manufacturerTypeId  manufacturerRoles                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 LoanID  ManufacturerId  LoanAmount  LoanDate    RefundId  manufacturerId  RefundAmount  RefundDate
```

---

```
         5  Saud       Jibran         0         0  8475983748G  HFDKJFH       VGHJXGVHJD         2015-04-29 14:12:20                    21  O:16:"clsEmployeeRoles":68:{s:56:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_RegionTypes";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:52:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:69:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_RegionStatistics";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:2;i:0;}s:82:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_     6               5  65644343:1:"2015-05-06Em       6               5  77744s_Station2015-05-06:{
         5  Saud       Jibran         0         0  8475983748G  HFDKJFH       VGHJXGVHJD         2015-04-29 14:12:20                    21  O:16:"clsEmployeeRoles":68:{s:56:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_RegionTypes";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:52:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:69:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_RegionStatistics";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:2;i:0;}s:82:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_    13               5  543543;s:1:"2015-05-07Em       6               5  77744s_Station2015-05-06:{
         7  Naveed     Ahmed          0         0  847893       hfkjhfskj     fjksddshkfjdshfkj  2015-04-29 14:22:16                    19  O:16:"clsEmployeeRoles":68:{s:56:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_RegionTypes";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:52:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:69:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_RegionStatistics";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:2;i:0;}s:82:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_    16               7  8798u656:1:"2015-05-07Em       9               7  4354334Station2015-05-07:{
         7  Naveed     Ahmed          0         0  847893       hfkjhfskj     fjksddshkfjdshfkj  2015-04-29 14:22:16                    19  O:16:"clsEmployeeRoles":68:{s:56:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_RegionTypes";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:52:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:69:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_RegionStatistics";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:2;i:0;}s:82:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_    16               7  8798u656:1:"2015-05-07Em      10               7  896789798ation2015-05-07:{
         7  Naveed     Ahmed          0         0  847893       hfkjhfskj     fjksddshkfjdshfkj  2015-04-29 14:22:16                    19  O:16:"clsEmployeeRoles":68:{s:56:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_RegionTypes";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:52:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:69:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_RegionStatistics";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:2;i:0;}s:82:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_    17               7  87987687:1:"2015-05-07Em       9               7  4354334Station2015-05-07:{
         7  Naveed     Ahmed          0         0  847893       hfkjhfskj     fjksddshkfjdshfkj  2015-04-29 14:22:16                    19  O:16:"clsEmployeeRoles":68:{s:56:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_RegionTypes";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:52:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions";a:4:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;}s:69:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_RegionStatistics";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:2;i:0;}s:82:"aEmployeeRole_Organization_RegionalHierarchy_Regions_    17               7  87987687:1:"2015-05-07Em      10               7  896789798ation2015-05-07:{
```

I have attached the pic of the output i am getting... 
tables are manufacturer,loan,refund, manufacutrerId is common in all tables.
now in the pic it shows repeated record as the manufacturer took loan 2 times but return amount 1 time.. but it repeats in refund column. Please Help !!!

Comment: Yes its possible if you provide DDL and sample data and expected result into the question.

Comment: Provided was editing the post .. sorry for little late

Comment: Can you simplify the problem to only include relevant columns. It would make it easier for us.

Comment: Yes, i just need firstname,refund amount,loan amount, remaining amount i.e = to loanmount - refundamount ... the query which andriy gave is working it sums up loan and refund data .. but it sums up all the fields which were repeated like the manufacturer refunded only once but it was showing 2 times in the records, now it sums up all the repeated records it gets from the db and second error is it is not subtracting refundamount from loanamount

Comment: `ManufacturerId  FirstName  LastName      LA      RA  RemainingAmount  
--------------  ---------  --------  ------  ------  -----------------
             5  Saud       Jibran       800     400                100
             7  Naveed     Ahmed        800     400                100`  now it shows 100 at the remaining amount it should show 400.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
SELECT ManufacturerId,FirstName,LA,RA, LA - RA as RemainingAmount FROM  (SELECT MM.ManufacturerId,MM. FirstName,SUM(LoanAmount) as LA, SUM(RefundAmount) as RA  FROM microfinance_manufacturers AS MM 
                INNER JOIN manufacturer_loans AS ML ON MM.ManufacturerId = Ml.ManufacturerId 
                INNER JOIN manufacturer_refunds AS MR ON MM.ManufacturerId = MR.manufacturerId
                GROUP BY MM.ManufacturerId) as a
```

Comment: im getting this error Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'LA' in 'field list'

Comment: Oh i checked again.. The query works but it gives me wrong info :( .. as it sums the refunds which is being repeated .`ManufacturerId  FirstName  LastName         LA          RA  RemainingAmount  
--------------  ---------  --------  ---------  ----------  -----------------
             5  Saud       Jibran     66187886      155488           65566599
             7  Naveed     Ahmed     175992970  1802288264           -4345536`

Comment: So you have repeated refounds, so maybe you should modify your query to SELECT statement to:
SUM(distinct RefundAmount) if refound amount is uniqie, or COUNT(distinct RefundId)  if counter of unique IDs is enough for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the aggregations *before* the `join`.  Otherwise, you end up with a cartesian product that throws off the values:

```
SELECT MM.*, ML.*, MR.* 
FROM microfinance_manufacturers MM left join
     (select Ml.ManufacturerId, count(*) as numloans, sum(ml.amount) as loanamount
      from manufacturer_loans ML
      group by ManufacturerId
     ) ml
     on MM.ManufacturerId = Ml.ManufacturerId left join
     (select Mr.ManufacturerId, count(*) as numrefunds, sum(ml.amount) as refundamount
      from manufacturer_refunds mr
      group by ManufacturerId
     ) mr
     on MM.ManufacturerId = MR.manufacturerId;
```

Your question is unclear both on the data layout and on the expected results.  But this should be basically what you need.

Comment: i am getting this error 
Error Code: 1066
Not unique table/alias: 'ml'